# I need a way to see which of my db tables are not empty, but I am strugling with the syntax a bit

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I use a reference table that references schemas (table names) by schemaid. 
I need to run a SELECT count(*) from T(table) where count(*) > 0
But only for those tables with CORE:Table in the name. The substitution for the (table) I thought I could do by DECLARING @schemaset and then use the while loop to process it. I am more used to FOR loop, but MSSQL does not seem to have that.

```
DECLARE @schemaset VARCHAR

WHILE @schemaset in (select schemaId from arschema where name like 'CORE:Table%')

BEGIN
  select COUNT(*) from T(@schemaset)where FIELD1 IS NOT NULL
END
```

Query runs, but it says it completed successfully. I tried PRINT to see the results, but that complained with an error.

So, how do I get a full/empty check on a set of specific tables?

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need looping or dynamic sql for this. This will return all tables that have zero rows with a single select statement.

```
SELECT TableName = t.name 
    , TableRowCount = SUM(p.rows)
    , SchemaName = s.name
FROM sys.partitions AS p
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON p.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE p.index_id IN (0, 1) -- heap or clustered index
group by t.name
    , s.name
having SUM(p.rows) = 0
order by t.name
```

Comment: Might want to group by `object_id` as well in case the same table name is in two different schemas or might want to include schema name.

Comment: --EDIT-- Added schema name just in case in you have multiple objects with the same name in different schemas. Thanks to @SqlZim for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of SQL that will return all empty tables:

```
-- All Empty Tables
CREATE TABLE #counts (table_name sysname,row_count int)

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable @command1='INSERT #counts (table_name, row_count) SELECT ''?'', COUNT(*) FROM ?'
SELECT table_name AS EmptyTables, row_count 
FROM #counts 
WHERE row_count = 0
ORDER BY table_name
DROP TABLE #counts
GO
```

A different strategy that doesn't rely on the undocumented "sp_MSForEachTable" stored procedure, and which lets you filter which tables you want to examine, looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
CREATE TABLE #Counts (Table_Name sysname, Row_Count int);
SET @sql = N'';
SELECT @sql += N'INSERT INTO #Counts (Table_Name, Row_Count) SELECT ''' + TABLE_NAME + 
               N''', COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + N'; '
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE N'A%'
PRINT @sql;
EXEC(@sql);
SELECT * FROM #Counts
DROP TABLE #Counts
```

The SELECT statement filters the list of tables to only those in the 'dbo' schema, and only those that start with the letter 'A'.  You can alter this to fit your needs, filtering for any tables you wish.

Basically what this code is doing is building up a series of INSERT statements for each table, inserting the COUNT and the table name into the temporary table. You can massage this to do any sort of thing you wish... this is purely an example.

Comment: This solution also works, Thank you pmbAustin. However, I need to also include the "name" from the schema table where I have schemaid and names mapped. That's why I need the while loop that allows me to qualify the query with the first 3 chars of the table name.

Comment: That requirement doesn't negate the use of this ... just change the FROM and WHERE in the SELECT statement to fit your needs. You still don't need any WHILE loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tweak to the above logic, for practical reasons your output needs the schema (as multiple schemas may exist), and the logic above breaks if there are schemas other than dbo

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max); 
CREATE TABLE #Counts (Table_Name sysname, Row_Count int); 
SET @sql = N''; 
SELECT @sql += N'INSERT INTO #Counts (Table_Name, Row_Count) SELECT ''' + 
    TABLE_SCHEMA +'.'+ TABLE_NAME + 
    N''', COUNT(*) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' 
    QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + N'; '   
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES    
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE N'%' AND 
    TABLE_NAME LIKE N'%'  
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME 
PRINT @sql; 
EXEC(@sql); 
SELECT * FROM #Counts 
DROP TABLE #Counts
```